# How do I format tables in Google Documents?

Tags: google-docs

I have uploaded a Word document to Google Drive that contains a table.
I am trying to format the margins and table etc. Tried everything.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Select the desired rows to get rid of padding, go to "Format" then "Line Spacing" then "Custom Spacing". The preset "After" is "16"; decrease that to the desired amount.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of several approaches.

1. Format everything the way you want it in Word before you put it in Drive.  An easy way to do this is to install Drive on your computer, and have Drive running all the time, so that synchronizing happens automatically.
2. Make sure you upload the file as a Word document (without converting to gdoc); if you need to tweak something, use a Chrome extension called [Office Editing for Docs, Sheets & Slides](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office-editing-for-docs-s/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj?hl=en).
3. Re-learn all the formatting techniques you already know how to do in Word, but now with the gdocs software.  I have wrestled with this, and I do not recommend this approach personally.  However, apparently there are many people in the world who are happy with this approach.  For example, highlight some or all cells in a table, right-click and choose Table Properties.  Now you can edit "Cell padding."

I'm not sure what you mean by the margin.  If it's the margins on the page, go into File -> Page setup.

Make sure you are able to edit by looking at View -> Mode and making sure you are in "Editing" or "Suggesting" not "Viewing".

You might find the Paragraph Styles add-on helpful.