# How to split table columns independently

Tags: google-docs

How can I create a table in Google Docs that has two columns, with the left column being split into three rows and the right column split into 9 rows, but so that I can change the height and of the cells on the right side independently from the left?

If I first create a table with two cells and then split the left one horizontally into three sub cells and then the right one into nine, then every third horizontal line is connected between left and right and I can’t move them independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Docs table editor is very simple.

One option is to keep using the Google Docs table editor, an alternative is to use another app to create the table that you needs then import / paste into your Google Docs document, i.e. you might create the table using HTML, open it in your browser, copy the rendered table and paste it into the Google Docs Document. Also you could use Microsoft Word or another similar word processor app.

If you decide to keep using one the Google Docs table editor, here are the instructions to have a starting point:

1. Insert a table with one row and two columns.
2. On each cell, insert a table with one row and one column.

[image]

3. Split each inner cell as you need.
   [image]
4. Adjust the tables / cells borders and margings.

Related

- [Nested tables in Google Docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/54132/88163)
- [How do I format tables in Google Documents?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/80266/88163)
- [Can I split cells within a table?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/110737/88163)

Comment: this looks like what I've been looking for, thank you!